# Unable To Connect To SharePoint DB on Virtual Machine

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql-server, vmware

I am trying to install SharePoint 2013 Foundation on a virtual machine I have (vmware with Windows Server 2012) and connect the SharePoint to SQL Server which installed on a different virtual machine (also WS2012).

As this is just a testing environment I want to omit creating domain account and using SharePoint 2013 management PowerShell console running the "New-SPConfigurationDatabase" where I can specify DB name, Server name and a local user credentials.

My issue is that once I run the above mentioned command I am not able to find DB and getting error message saying that DB might not existing. Coudld you please navigate how can I point the wizard to find the DB which installed on another virtual machine (which is connected by virtual network to the SP installation one).

Comment: Can you ping the sql server from the SharePoint box??

Comment: I don't know If I'm doing it in right way but not. I am able to ping another virtual machine by its IP address but when I ping SQLEXPRESS or computername/SQLEXPRESS then no luck

Comment: It seems like a dns problem. Check that you are usimg an internal dns server on the SharePoint box and that you have a A or CNAME record that connects the sql server name with is IP address

Comment: Could be a firewall issue. Also, check if setting up an alias helps. You can map DBS-server's IP to a name @ SP-server side. `C:\Windows\System32\cliconfg.exe` (or see full tutorial @ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2012/08/06/install-amp-configure-sharepoint-2013-with-sql-client-alias.aspx)

Comment: I disabled firewall temporary and can ping the server by its name eg. SERVERNAME but not able to ping the SQLEXPRESS db

Comment: SQLEXPRESS is a named instance of SQL Server, it's not meant to be pingable. Are you passing "SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS" to `New-SPConfigurationDatabase`?

Comment: Thanks for responses but I found the mistake I made, I posted solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to connect to the DB. There was just a naming issue where to solve it I used SQLEXPRESS as a DB name and SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS as a server name.